# how to select the nth instance in a SQL count?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table where each row has a user id and the timestamp they started a level.

```
user    timestamp
1   2018-11-04
1   2018-11-07
1   2018-11-09
1   2018-11-09
2   2019-11-02
2   2019-11-03
2   2019-11-06
3   2019-11-10
3   2019-11-13
3   2019-11-15
```

I need to select the timestamp for the 2nd time a user has started a level. I tried: `

```
select distinct user, timestamp 
from table,
  (select user, count(*) 
   from table
    group by 1
    having count(outcome) > 1) tbl
where table.user = tbl.user and count(*) = 2
```

Expected Results:

```
user    timestamp
1   2018-11-07
2   2019-11-03
3   2019-11-13
```

Any help would be appreciated! (apologies if the formatting is off, my first question here.

Comment: Post the expected data

Comment: Thanks-- updated the question to include that

Comment: What SQL flavour are you using? MySQL5.x, MySQL8+, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, ???

Comment: I'm working in snowflake, which is pretty similar to MySQL-- uses ANSI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a DBMS that supports CTEs and window functions, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` and select the second row for each `user`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY timestamp) AS rn
    FROM times
)
SELECT user, timestamp
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 2
```

Note you don't really need CTE's, you can just write the CTE as a subquery:

```
SELECT user, timestamp
FROM (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY timestamp) AS rn
    FROM times
) t
WHERE rn = 2
```

Output

```
user    timestamp
1       2018-11-07
2       2019-11-03
3       2019-11-13
```

[MySQL 8 demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4ftwe9hs3r6LRvJgtrHWjs/1)

Comment: I don't have anywhere to test this but it should work on snowflake.

Answer (score 2):

**You do not need to use a subquery for this as Snowflake supports [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html).**

I think this function only exists in Teradata apart from Snowflake, why I don't really understand, as it is extremely convenient. From the docs: `In a SELECT statement, the QUALIFY clause filters the results of window functions`. So use `ROW_NUMBER()` with partition on `User` ordered by `TimeStamp` to create and filter on an ordering number on the fly.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user ORDER BY timestamp) = 2;
```

Result:

```
USER    TIMESTAMP
3       2019-11-13
2       2019-11-03
1       2018-11-07
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use dense_rank to set ranking and then use nested query to get userId with rank 2(when user second time access the system) only.

```
SELECT USERID,TIMESTAMP
    FROM (
        SELECT *
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY USERID ORDER BY TIMESTAMP
                ) AS STAMPRANK
        FROM DEMOTABLE
        ) T
    WHERE T.STAMPRANK = 2
```

Comment: Dense_rank will have ties at the same rank. If the second row had the same date then it would still have rank 1 and would not be returned. Row_number appears to fits this specific use case bettee.

Comment: Yes, you are right @davidgarrison, we should replace dense_rank with row_number instead. Thanks.